# Bigquery unnest function

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

What is the correct SQL code to transform this table:

| user_id | event_params.key | event_params.string_value | event_params.int_value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | event_label | load |  |
|  | event_category |  | 4 |

Into this table:

| user_id | event_label | event_category |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | load | 4 |

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What you tried to do? What exactly a trouble?

Comment: You need to use pivot, see https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#pivot_operator
Then show some effort that you tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to [unnest](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/arrays#scanning_for_values_that_satisfy_a_condition) the array so that you can query it.

After replacing `my_dataset` and `my_table` the following should return what you desire:

```
select 
  user_id,
  (
    select param.string_value 
    from unnest(event_params) as param 
    where param.key = 'event_label'
  ) as event_label,
  (
    select param.int_value
    from unnest(event_params) as param 
    where param.key = 'event_category'
  ) as event_category,
from my_dataset.my_table
```

---

*[ga4sql.com](https://www.ga4sql.com/) website should help you to generate these kind of queries for GA4.*

Answer (score 0):

Consider also below option

```
select * from (
  select user_id, event.*
  from your_table, unnest(event_params) event
)
pivot (any_value(greatest(ifnull(string_value, ''), ifnull('' || int_value, ''))) for key in ('event_label', 'event_category'))
```

with output

[image]